# How do I make a corner that that curves wide on the bottom and smaller along the edges like this in Blender? Using the bevel tool does not work as exp

Tags: bevel

This is the Corner I want to make. So that it curves wide on the bottom region then a smaller curve along the edges.

[image: Corner]

However every time I use the bevel tool it stretches into the entire corner.

[image]

I have edited the original mesh and better use of the bevel modifier but I'm still not able to get a good shape such as the one on the image.

[image]

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Apply the scale to your object (Ctrl-A > Scale in Object mode) before bevelling and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want independent control over the the width of a bevel along each of the loops it crosses, then you can set its **Width Type** to 'Percent'.  Here, that's done with a *Bevel* modifier, with Limit Method set to 'Weight', rather than an operator, to allow precise adjustment:

[image]

If the resulting topology doesn't suit, you can apply the modifier to freeze the bevel, and dissolve away the loops which controlled it.

(In the illustration, the small 'trim' bevel, rounding the edges, is another *Bevel* modifier, by Angle, after the 'form' *Bevel*, (by Weight)  which is being adjusted.  Personally I find it practical to think of those as different things.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to beginners to explain why the edge is blue and how you are getting bevel weight to the edge and how to use it...

Comment: Hi, @Gordon .. is that not clear enough from the bottom paragraph? Maybe not.. feel free to edit, always useful to have another pair of eyes.. :)

Comment: To me it's superclear, to beginners? And how to get a weight on the edge in the first place? But I guess that's something they can easily google.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann .. to my mind, that wasn't central to the problem, no need for OP to be manipulating 2 bevels at once.. could do the form first, apply, and then do the trim. Now these comments are here, they'll probably serve as well as any edit, so between us, we've probably got where we wanted to go . :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. Please see the updated topic. I can't find any part of blenders document that describe weight painting to shape a bevel.

Comment: Hi, @Daniel! That isn't weight painting. It's Edge Bevel Weight, a separate setting available in the N-panel of your 3D view. (There's no need to use it, if you do your large bevel followed by your small one.. I'm only using it in modifiers, so I can conveniently adjust both bevels at the same time,)

Comment: Hi Robin, sorry. Still no go. I'm basically trying to make a dial up phone but the base is confusing me.  https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=dial+up+phone

Comment: Hi, @Daniel.. here, you can make your wide bevels first,on the vertical edges, to get the curved corners on the form, and then the small 'trim' bevel on the remaining sharp edges